# It is not the latest map when using google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**My Problem is I can not get the latest map through google map api**

When I search `NW Debron Ln, Bend, OR 97701` on google map **directly**, I get the map like this,

[image]

[Google Maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/NW+Debron+Ln,+Bend,+OR+97701/@44.0764885,-121.3496588,140m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x54b8c8f771112f2b:0x58ee32e929fe192c)

But when I use the map **api** on my app, the map looks like this, there are not some buildings.

[image]

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I want to get the latest map when using the API

Comment: @duncan dont me rude, it can be easily implied what his problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off the 45 degree imagery.  Those tiles are older, the straight satellite images are newer and show the homes and homes under construction.  Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#Enabling45DegreeImagery), disable the 45 degree imagery by using `google.maps.Map.setTilt(0)`.

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        //Northwest Debron Lane, Bend, OR 97701, USA (44.0764875, -121.3496508)
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.0764875, -121.3496508),
        zoom: 19,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });
    map.setTilt(0);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```